# Get the values from json string in pipeline groovy script

Tags: json, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I had json string value. I need to get the values from the json string. I have to try to convert the json string to json object and then get the value.

I have try the below steps to convert the json string into json object.

```
import groovy.js
def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(str).on.JsonSlurper
```

But I have facing below error while get the values.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {message=org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified field java.lang.String id} for EchoStep(message: String): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EchoStep.message expects class java.lang.String but received class org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException.

Kindly give a better suggestion to get the values from json string in groovy

Note:I didn't restrict script approval.

Comment: Show your json string please?

Answer (score 0):

First, I find that Jenkins plays better with JsonSlurperClassic.

`def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(str)` is all you need to make the json object, which is an odd mappy-listy object. You can reference it like you would a map that had arrays in it: `slurper.mapvalone[0].mapvaltwo[0]`.